# HIIT timer with exercise?

Tags: hiit, app

Is there an app / website thats a HIT timer but also chooses the exercise for you?

Ive Googled this and look on app stores but I can only find timers only. With some you can set the exercises you want to do but non pick them for you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"chooses the exercise for you"*?

Comment: As in tell me first set it push ups, second set is squats, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [YAYOG](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjouO-ioqLXAhWGORoKHeMlB6UQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.leafcutterstudios.yayog%26hl%3Dde&usg=AOvVaw2IgajkZC3Pjgmkvp-V-dsO) app lets you define your custom workouts. They have multiple exercise types, including Tabatas, which are HIIT intervals with 20 s load and 10 s rest. You could - for example - create a Tabata workout with 10 rounds (3 min) of push ups and 10 rounds of squats.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Freeletics](https://www.freeletics.com). There are many workouts you can choose from, most of them being HIT workouts based on bodyweight exercises. I don't know, if there actually are HIIT workouts, but it's definitely conceivable. There are some free workouts, but for most of them you'll need to have a subscription.

You can start the workouts both from the website and from the app. Both will keep track of your times and guide you through the workouts.